# SQL Error: ORA-02291: integrity constraint, parent key not found

Tags: sql, oracle

This is the table that I'm trying to insert the values into:

```
CREATE TABLE SESSIONS(
SESSIONID CHAR(4) NOT NULL,
BRANCHID CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
SCREENID CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
MOVIEID CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
SESSIONDATE DATE,
SESSIONPRICE NUMBER(4,2),
CONSTRAINT SESSIONS_PK PRIMARY KEY(SESSIONID, BRANCHID, SCREENID, MOVIEID),
CONSTRAINT SESSIONS_FK1 FOREIGN KEY(SCREENID, BRANCHID) REFERENCES SCREEN(SCREENID, BRANCHID),
CONSTRAINT SESSIONS_FK2 FOREIGN KEY(MOVIEID) REFERENCES MOVIE(MOVIEID));
```

And when populating the table I get the error that says the cause is that a foreign key value has no matching primary key value. I was able to insert all the rows except for one. I'm unsure as to why I'm getting this error?

```
INSERT INTO SESSIONS VALUES ('SS01', 'B1', 'S1', 'M1', '3-May-16', 12.50);
INSERT INTO SESSIONS VALUES ('SS02', 'B2', 'S1', 'M2', '4-Jun-16', 19.45); // Line where the error occurs
INSERT INTO SESSIONS VALUES ('SS03', 'B1', 'S2', 'M2', '3-May-16', 12.67);
INSERT INTO SESSIONS VALUES ('SS04', 'B4', 'S2', 'M4', '13-May-16', 14.56);
INSERT INTO SESSIONS VALUES ('SS05', 'B3', 'S2', 'M5', '23-May-16', 14.56);
INSERT INTO SESSIONS VALUES ('SS06', 'B3', 'S1', 'M5', '3-Jun-16', 16.32);
INSERT INTO SESSIONS VALUES ('SS07', 'B4', 'S2', 'M3', '14-May-16', 21.78);
INSERT INTO SESSIONS VALUES ('SS08', 'B1', 'S2', 'M2', '6-Jun-16', 16.82);
INSERT INTO SESSIONS VALUES ('SS09', 'B2', 'S3', 'M4', '13-May-16', 17.90);
INSERT INTO SESSIONS VALUES ('SS10', 'B4', 'S1', 'M3', '6-Jun-16', 16.37);
```

Comment: Apparently there are no matching row for one of the foreign keys. Can't tell you which one because you haven't specified data for those tables.

Comment: Because pair 'B2'-'S1' doesnt exists in parent table, I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are running this query,

```
INSERT INTO SESSIONS VALUES ('SS02', 'B2', 'S1', 'M2', '4-Jun-16', 19.45);
```

Then check with `MOVIE` table that the `MOVIEID` present in the table.
And again check with `SCREEN(SCREENID, BRANCHID)`, check the combination is same as you are inserting.

You got this error when the same data is not present in the referenced table.

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your MOVIE and SCREEN table are populated and 'M2' or 'S1' value exist in them.